# Error: Process completed with exit code 2

Tags: docker, github-actions

This snippet from GitHub Actions workflow is giving the following error:

```yaml
      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        env:
          COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL: "true"
        # This step uses the identity token to provision an ephemeral certificate
        # against the sigstore community Fulcio instance.
        run: docker run --rm --entrypoint=sh -v ${{ github.workspace }}:${{ github.workspace }} sigstore/cosign:v1.4.0 -c "cosign sign --force ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}@${{ steps.build-and-push.outputs.digest }}"
```

This is the entire workflow:

```yaml
name: docker-ghcr-workflow

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  # schedule:
  #   - cron: '30 22 * * *'
  push:
    branches: main
    # Publish semver tags as releases.
    tags: 'v*.*.*'
  pull_request:
    branches: main

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: kalpanamamnani/todo_app
  # IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}
  IMAGE_TAG: 1.0.${{ github.run_number }} # GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER }}

jobs:
  build-push-docker:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      # This is used to complete the identity challenge
      # with sigstore/fulcio when running outside of PRs.
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Install the cosign tool except on PR
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign-installer
      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@1e95c1de343b5b0c23352d6417ee3e48d5bcd422
        with:
          cosign-release: 'v1.4.0'

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v1
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: todo_app
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} # ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          # tags: ghcr.io/houssemdellai/github-actions-course:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} # ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      # Sign the resulting Docker image digest except on PRs.
      # This will only write to the public Rekor transparency log when the Docker
      # repository is public to avoid leaking data.  If you would like to publish
      # transparency data even for private images, pass --force to cosign below.
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign
      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        env:
          COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL: "true"
        # This step uses the identity token to provision an ephemeral certificate
        # against the sigstore community Fulcio instance.
        run: docker run --rm --entrypoint=sh -v ${{ github.workspace }}:${{ github.workspace }} sigstore/cosign:v1.4.0 -c "cosign sign --force ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}@${{ steps.build-and-push.outputs.digest }}"
```

Comment: Please include the complete log. Looks like that non-zero exit code is coming from the container itself. That's why that step is failing. It must be from `cosign sign` command.